# Change Image for a Range in UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Is there any way to change the Trackimage for a Range in UISlider, independent from the Position of the Thumb?

It should look like this:

[image: Slider]

I already have the Slider without the yellow Range. How can i achieve the yellow Range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your deployment target is at least iOS 6.0,** you can do this using `UIImageResizingModeTile`.  Example code:

```
static UIImage *blueYellowStripesImage() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 9), YES, 0); {
        [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 9));
        [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 9));
        [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.4] setFill];
        UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, 5, 100, 4), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    }
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
    return image;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = blueYellowStripesImage();
    [self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Result:

[image: slider with tiled image tracks]